# Can someone hack applications if we do validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

Actually i had done client side validation using java script.One of my senior  told that if we use java script for validation hackers will hack our application using some web scripts i don't know about web script can anyone tell is it true? if true how?

Comment: You should ask this question to the senior who told you in the first place!

Comment: *The server should always validate data sent to it.* A user/hacker can run their own JavaScript on a web page bypassing your scripts, or JavaScript may be disabled, or they might just make a manual request to your server using a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

well yes it is true for me. only javascript verification can't be safe.

here was post about this so you can check it:

[Is JavaScript validation bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945005/is-javascript-validation-bad)

Comment: then how we can do client side validation

Comment: i will tell you simple example of verification. you will create numbers in server for (1234) and save it in session after that you will show this numbers with javascript and when user will submit numbers you can check if entered numbers and session saved numbers is same. with only javascript you can't store this kind of value safe because javascript is client side language and clients always can manipulate in javascript values

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (for a web page) is just there to make the web experience from the users perspective more responsive and interactive.

It can be turned off - or the Javascript corrupted.

So do not trust it.

All responses to the server should be mistrusted and validated/verified.

PS: Look up SQL injection